# First element of each dataframe partition Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partition

I need to retrieve the first element of each dataframe partition. 
I know that I need to use mapPartitions but it is not clear for me how to use it.

Note: I am using Spark2.0, the dataframe is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should look something like following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
...
implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(df.schema)
val newDf = df.mapPartitions(iterator => iterator.take(1))
```

This will take 1 element from each partition in DataFrame. Then you can collect all the data to your driver i.e.:

```
nedDf.collect()
```

This will return you an array with a number of elements equal to number of your partitions.

**UPD** updated in order to support Spark 2.0

Comment: I'm looking at method signature here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html and wonder don't you need Encoder as the second parameter in this method call?

Comment: Trying this solution returns " Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._" even using spar.implicits, the errors persists

Comment: Replacing mapPartitions with foreachPartition works but it is returning an empty list ()

Comment: Do you mean `collect` ? It returns Array of Rows. The `mapPartitions` operation without `collect` will return a new DataFrame.